# How to change div css attribute none to block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

In my project, I use ajax to fetch html content to cenDiv div.

My ajax code is:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'html',
  type: "POST",
  url: "oat.php",
  data: {
    standby: standby
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $("#cenDiv").html(data);
    $.parser.parse($('#corWSId').parent());
  }
});
```

My oat.php code is:

```
if(isset($_POST['inAppInit']))
{   
 echo '
   ........
   <div style="display:none" id="attFId">...</div>
   <div style="display:block" id="attNId">...</div>
   ........
  ';
}
```

Now, I want to change display of both. My js function is:

```
function storFirDoc() {
  var docTV = $('#docTitle').val();
  if (docTV == "") {
    alert("not none");
    exit;
  } else {
    alert('test'); //works Ok
    //loadjscssfile('jsui/easyui-1.5.3/jquery.min.js', "js"); 
    //loadjscssfile('jsui/easyui-1.5.3/jquery.easyui.min.js', "js"); 
    $('#attNId').css('display', 'block'); //works fail
    $('#attFId').css('display', 'none'); //works fail
  }
}
```

I know that `attNId` and `attFId`  can not be found in DOM for they both from ajax return. So I use `loadjscssfile` function to reload js head js. But it failed again.

Who can help me ?

Comment: try using delegate..!

Comment: Where do you call the `storFirDoc` function?

Comment: Use your `storFirDoc()` function INSIDE the success function of your ajax call. Or, make sure it isn't called until those elements are on the page.

Comment: $('#attNId').show()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#attNId').attr("style", "display:none");
$('#attFId').attr("style", "display:block");
```

works fine

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine for you.

```
$('#attNId').show();
$('#attFId').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `complete: function()` in ajax call.

So when your ajax data loaded complatly then your storFirDoc() function call. like below.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'html',
    type: "POST",
    url: "oat.php",
    data: {
    standby: standby
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $("#cenDiv").html(data);
        $.parser.parse($('#corWSId').parent());
    }
    complete: function () {
        var docTV = $('#docTitle').val();
        if (docTV == "") {
            alert("not none");
            exit;
        } else {
        alert('test'); //works Ok
            //loadjscssfile('jsui/easyui-1.5.3/jquery.min.js', "js"); 
            //loadjscssfile('jsui/easyui-1.5.3/jquery.easyui.min.js', "js"); 
            $('#attNId').css('display', 'block'); //works fail
            $('#attFId').css('display', 'none'); //works fail
        }
    }
});
```